# Why using with() as function in a map() call does not work in this example?

Tags: r, purrr

```
library(tidyverse)

formulas <- list(
  mpg ~ disp,
  mpg ~ I(1 / disp),
  mpg ~ disp + wt,
  mpg ~ I(1 / disp) + wt
)

# this works
map(formulas, ~ {lm(.x, mtcars)}) 

# this doesn't
map(formulas, ~ {with(mtcars, lm(.x))}) 

 Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'disp' not found
```

Working through the exercises in https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html#exercises-28, I tried to solve exercise number 6, by trying to evaluate `lm()` inside `mtcars` environment with `with()`, but it throws an error.

Why the last call doesn't work?

Comment: It wouldn't work on a single formula as well `with(mtcars, lm(formulas[[1]]))`

Comment: Note that `with(mtcars, lm(mpg ~ disp))` here the environment is correct while `with(mtcars, lm(formulas[[1]]))`, it is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the environment issue. One option would be `quote` the components so that it would not be executed

```
formulas <- list(
  quote(mpg ~ disp),
  quote(mpg ~ I(1 / disp)),
   quote(mpg ~ disp + wt),
  quote(mpg ~ I(1 / disp) + wt)
  )

out1 <- map(formulas, ~ with(mtcars, lm(eval(.x))))
out1
#[[1]]

#Call:
#lm(formula = eval(.x))

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)         disp  
#   29.59985     -0.04122  


#[[2]]

#Call:
#lm(formula = eval(.x))

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)    I(1/disp)  
#      10.75      1557.67  


#[[3]]

#Call:
#lm(formula = eval(.x))

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)         disp           wt  
#   34.96055     -0.01772     -3.35083  


#[[4]]

#Call:
#lm(formula = eval(.x))

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)    I(1/disp)           wt  
#     19.024     1142.560       -1.798
```

It should also work with the first method

```
out2 <- map(formulas, ~ lm(.x, mtcars))
```

There would be slight changes in the attributes and in the `call`, but if that is ignored,

```
out1[[1]]$call <- out2[[1]]$call
all.equal(out1[[1]], out2[[1]], check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```